# Can I specify the style of plot for some element in discrete plot?

Tags: plotting, style

I am using discrete plot to plot a 1D array. But I want to plot some points specified by a span in one style (for example, in red) and the rest points in other style (e.g. in blue).

Comment: What did you try? Which functions? Any sample data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works pretty like you already said it. You can use [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Span.html) to extract any interval of points you like. If you then plot a list of intervals with e.g. `ListPlot`, you can style them all differently

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, .1}];
ListPlot[{data[[;; 43]], data[[44 ;;]]},
 PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Blue}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]